# Reading a formatted text file + Extracting certain information + Loading it into a JList

Tags: java, swing, file, jlist

So here I got my code that would read a text file:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadTextFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("Test.txt");
        StringBuffer contents = new StringBuffer();
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String text = null;

            // repeat until all lines is read
            while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                contents.append(text).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // show file contents here
        System.out.println(contents.toString());
    }
}
```

Ok, now I need my text file (Test.txt) to have the following structure (Example):

```
topic:- <climate>subtopic1, <atmosphere_type>subtopic2

subtopic1:- <temperatures>sentence1, <gases>sentence2, <winds>sentence3
subtopic2:- <gas_composition>sentence4, <gravitational_weight>sentence5

sentence1:- temperatures are around 34ºC but they can reach -42ºC in winter
sentence2:- there are significant proportions of nitrogen (13%) and butane (24%)
sentence3:- there are permanent winds with gusts of 118 km/h
sentence4:- methane (48%), nitrogen (13%), butane (24%) and oxygen (12%)
sentence5:- gravity in ecuador is 7.95 atmospheres
```

What I really need is to have 2 `JList`, where in the first `JList` I could choose a topic (Like "climate" or "atmosphere type") and then on my second `JList` I'd select a subtopic (If I choose "climate", then I could choose "temperatures", "gases" or "winds"), so when I hit a `JButton`, the program would show me the corresponding sentence. Is it hard to do something like that? Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Re-asking the same question isn't acceptable behavior here.  If you want to draw attention to your question, you will be allowed to [place a bounty on it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) after two days.  You can also [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5931649/edit) to add additional information, which may make your question easier to understand and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to build the following data structures from the file.

```
// map of a topic (or subtopic) name to a list of subtopic (or sentence) names
Map<String, List<String>> subtopics = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

// The above will contain the entries:
// topic -> [subtopic1, subtopic2]
// subtopic1 -> [sentence1, sentence2, sentence3]
// subtopic2 -> [sentence4, sentence5]

// map of topic/sentence name to heading
Map<String, String> headings = new HashMap<String, String>();

// This will contain:
// subtopic1 -> climate
// subtopic2 -> atmosphere type
// sentence1 -> temperatures
// sentence2 -> gases
// sentence3 -> winds
// sentence4 -> gas composition
// sentence5 -> gravitational weight

// dictionary for looking up a sentence name and retrieving its corresponding text
Map<String, String> dict = new HashMap<String, String>();

// sentence1 -> temperatures are around 34ºC but they can reach -42ºC in winter
// sentence2 -> there are significant proportions of nitrogen (13%) and butane (24%)
// sentence3 -> there are permanent winds with gusts of 118 km/h
// sentence4 -> methane (48%), nitrogen (13%), butane (24%) and oxygen (12%)
// sentence5 -> gravity in ecuador is 7.95 atmospheres
```

This should get you going in a good direction. One bit to watch for is when adding a topic to the 'subtopics' map for the first time, you have to remember to first create the List (e.g. an ArrayList), add the subtopic name to the list and and the list as the value for the topic name. If the topic name is found in the list, just add the subtopic name to the existing List.